# I want to append dynamic titles to <a> tag which is static for now

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging">
 <li>
     <a href="#" title="#IR201800" class="flex-active">1</a>
 </li>
 <li>
     <a href="#" title="#IR201800">2</a>
 </li>
 <li>
      <a href="#" title="#IR201800">3</a>
 </li>
</ol>
```

Currently the `title="#IR201800"`.
It's static and I want to append the title dynamically.

I've tried this code:

```
function appendTitles() {
  $(".slides").find(".flex-control-paging li").each(function() {
    var atag = $(this).parents('li').find('a');
    atag.attr("title", "Raaj");
  })
}
```

Comment: How would you like to do that? Where are the values supposed to come from?

Comment: i have the list of values i just dont understand that how to use selector

Comment: Please update your question to include them

Answer (score 1):

Loop and assign value using `attr` like this.

```js
var title = ['a', 'b', 'c']; // Your dynamic content List
$('ol > li').find('a').each(function(index, element) {
  $(this).attr('title', title[index])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging">
  <li>
    <a href="#" title="#IR201800" class="flex-active">1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" title="#IR201800">2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" title="#IR201800">3</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Ok validate answer for future :) Happy Coding :)

Comment: i did validate but site wont let me as i'm having very few reputation points

Comment: That means accept answer for future. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

```
function appendTitles() {
        $(".slides").find(".flex-control-paging li").each(function(){
            var atag = $(this).find('a');
            atag.attr("title", "Raaj");
        })
}
```

Try this. parent() is not needed.

Please check the fiddle
[here](https://jsfiddle.net/4fwsvufn/1/)

Comment: It dosen't work. It is not going inside the Each loop so i think i have used wron selector

Comment: I have added the fiddle. It is working for me. seems like you have the wrong selector some where.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're looking for this solution:

```js
function appendTitles() {
        $(".slides").find(".flex-control-paging li").each(function(){
            var atag = $(this).parent().find('a');
            atag.attr("title", "Raaj");
        })
}

appendTitles();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='slides'>
<ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging">
 <li>
     <a href="#" title="#IR201800" class="flex-active">1</a>
 </li>
 <li>
     <a href="#" title="#IR201800">2</a>
 </li>
 <li>
      <a href="#" title="#IR201800">3</a>
 </li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Here is the output:

```
<li>
 <a href="#" title="Raaj" class="flex-active">1</a>
</li>
```